# Combinatorial proof of ${{n}\choose{4}}={{n-3}\choose{4}}+3{{n-3}\choose{3}}+3{{n-3}\choose{2}}+n-3$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinations, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

I need help solving this problem ${{n}\choose{4}}={{n-3}\choose{4}}+3{{n-3}\choose{3}}+3{{n-3}\choose{2}}+n-3$. I was thinking for the LHS that I'm choosing 4 students to get a prize out of n students but I am not sure about the RHS. Please help.

Comment: Among those $n$ students who could get a prize, three of them are named **A**ndy, **B**ecky, and **C**hris and are considered special.  Break into cases based on how many of our special students got prizes and which ones.

Comment: Easier to see the patter if you write $n-3=\binom{n-3}{1}$ .

Comment: For future reference, this is a special case of the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof).

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm confused as to how that applies are A,B and C preferred for prizes or not preferred

Comment: @JMoravitz I think tyou should turn that comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split $n$ into two groups, $A$ and $B$, $|A| = n-3$ and $|B|=3$. This could correspond, for example, to some additional attribute of the $B$ group.

Then focus on the split of choices between the subgroups:

- choosing all from $A$ leads to $\dbinom{n-3}{4}$ options.
- choosing $3$ from $A$, $1$ from $B$ leads to $\dbinom{n-3}{3}\dbinom 31 = 3\dbinom{n-3}{3}$ options.
- choosing $2$ from $A$, $2$ from $B$ leads to $\dbinom{n-3}{2}\dbinom 32 = 3\dbinom{n-3}{2}$ options.
- choosing $1$ from $A$, $3$ from $B$ leads to $\dbinom{n-3}{1}\dbinom 33 = 1\dbinom{n-3}{1} = n-3$ options.

These cover all the possibilities from a simple choice of $4$ from the original $n$ so sum to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Use Vandermonde identity:
$$
\binom{n}{4}=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{n-3}{4-i}\binom{3}{i},
$$
which has the well-known combinatorial interpretation: if you have to choose $4$ objects on a total of $n$ objects, then it is the same of choosing $i$ in the first $3$ ones, and $4-i$ in the remaining ones, summing over $i\ge 0$.

Comment: I know how to prove this using algebra but I am supposed to something in this case students getting prizes in two different ways and get the RHS and LHS. We are not supposed to use algebra.

Comment: We are not using algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use *Pascal's relation* repeatedly:
$$\binom n4=\binom{n-1}{4}+\binom{n-1}3=\biggl[\binom{n-2}{4}+\binom{n-2}3\biggr]+\biggl[\binom{n-2}{3}+\binom{n-2}2\biggr]=\dotsm$$